# QGIS Export Satellite Imagery

Tags: qgis, google-maps, export, bing-maps

We cannot seem to find any way to export our projects as PNG/JPEG through the print layout/composer. We draw normal line and point SHP files over the Bing/Google Earth etc layers, but the exported image is simply blank with only our line and point layers showing.

We can sometimes get exports succesfully when the scale is over 3000, but due to the detailed information we need to depict, we need to get down to a scale of 1000.

Does anyone have any solutions or alternative options we can try?

Comment: What does 'does not work' mean? Do you get error messages? Does the program crash? Empty output? Burst into flames? all good definitions of 'does not work' with different potential fixes. It may be a bit antiquated but I can remember from years ago that Google disallowed exporting their image, either for PDF or hardcopy, this may still be the case - I haven't used Google in QGIS for a few years.

Comment: what have you tried so fare to tackle your problem?

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE. Could you tell us, which plugin or other solution you took to get the satellite imagery into your project? Also, please tell us which QGIS version you are using.

Comment: Thanks so much for the responses. 

When we export any satellite imagery (as a PNG/JPEG file), the satellite imagery is simply blank. It seems to work if we export at a larger scale. 

Can any of you export any form of satellite images at a scale of 1000 or smaller?

Answer (score 3):

The vendor is not allowing those images to be called/exported at large scale.  I've had the same experience with trying to export Esri basemaps in the layout.  You'll have to download the aerial image files (tif, jpeg, sid...etc) and load them in manually into Q, hit a public aerial WMS (in the US many states provide this or USGS provides a 1m service), or create and serve out your own aerial WMS to export against from your own image file repository.

Comment: Thank you so so much!!! The local area I'm in doesn't over this but I managed to find a copy that was older through a contact at the Council of Geoscience.